# SQL making new table from existing tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have this very basic problem and just can't figure out how to do it. I have two tables.

The first one, `users`, contains two columns: `id` which is just number representing a person and `sex`. Second column doesn't matter now.

The other table, `orders` has columns: `id_user`, `time`, `state`. The `id_user` refers to `id` in the first table. `state` has three different values (finished, canceled, new). I need to make a table that would show count of finished state (how many finished states one person has) next to the `id` of that person. I can run this thing:

```
select * , count(state) as CountOfFinished from orders
where state = 'finished' 
group by id_user;
```

to show me that information, but i need to have a table that would show `id`,`sex`, `CountOfFinished`.

I copied the first table to a new one, but don't know how to add the `CountOfFinished` column next to these two. I don't even know how to make a column out of it so I can join it or something.

Any idea what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a new table. What you want is a `JOIN`, or in this case, a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    u.id,
    u.sex,
    ISNULL(COUNT(o.state), 0) as CountOfFinished
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN orders o
    ON o.id_user = u.id
    AND o.state = 'finished'
GROUP BY
    u.id, u.sex
```

The above query will list all `users` and the number of finished `orders`. If you want to list only `users` with at least one finished `order`, use `INNER JOIN`.

---

To insert into a new table, create the table first and use `INSERT INTO`:

```
CREATE TABLE FinishedOrderCountByUser(
    UserId  INT,
    Sex     CHAR(1),
    CountOfFinished INT
)
INSERT INTO FinishedOrderCountByUser(UserId, Sex, CountOfFinished)
    SELECT
        u.id,
        u.sex,
        ISNULL(COUNT(o.state), 0) as CountOfFinished
    FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN orders o
        ON o.id_user = u.id
        AND o.state = 'finished'
    GROUP BY
        u.id, u.sex
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It works wihout the ISNULL thing, with it the values are all 0 in the CountOfFinished column, with the 0 after COUNT(o.state) it gives some error. The assignmen I got said "make a table" so I was trying to make one.

Comment: It should be`ISNULL(COUNT(o.state), 0)`.

Comment: Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: That's because the `ISNULL` function needs two arguments. The first one would be `COUNT(o.state)`, the 2nd is `0`. This means that if `COUNT(o.state)` is zero, meaning there are no finished order for that particular user, the value to be returned is `0` instead of `NULL`.